# when do i use "&" within scanf()?

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

This is my code:

```
int main() {
    int i,n, *arr;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    arr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    printf("%lld", sumOfArray(arr,n));

    return 0;
}
```

Why do I have to use `&arr[i]`? 
I thought that it's not needed when `arr` 
is of type `int *`.

Comment: Simply put, because `arr[i]` is where you want the value to be stored, so you need to pass a *pointer* to that place. You could have used `arr+i` too (because `arr` decays into a pointer type). Also, [don't cast the result of `malloc(3)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/2793118)

Comment: It's also better practice to use `sizeof(*arr)`

Comment: There is no need to use this. If you want to scan `int hello`, you would write `&hello`. And you can use (almost) any name you want for your pointer.

Comment: Don't cast malloc().

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves: `arr` actually is a pointer type. (yes, I was also missleaded by the name)

Comment: @Olaf Ah yeah, you're right. The name is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf()` takes a memory address, which it resolves to a pointer to push data to; `arr` on its own would be a pointer, but `arr[i]` is an int. Therefore, you need to pass the address of `arr[i]` to `scanf()`

Answer (score 1):

Although `arr` is of type `int *`, that's not where `scanf` is putting the data.  It's putting it in `arr[i]`, which is of type `int`.  Therefore, you need to pass the address of that variable, i.e. `&arr[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `&` to get the address of an object.

Which of these makes sense?

`scanf("%d", ...` needs an address of an `int` as the next argument.

---

`&n` is an `int *`.  Good

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
```

---

`arr` is an `int *`.  Good.

```
int *arr = malloc(1 * sizeof(*arr));
scanf("%d", arr);
```

---

`arr[i]` is an `int`: Bad

```
int *arr = malloc(n * sizeof(*arr));
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    scanf("%d", arr[i]); // bad
```

---

`&arr[i]` is an `int *`: Good

```
int *arr = malloc(n * sizeof(*arr));
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
```

---

`&arr[i]` is an `int *`: Good

```
int arr[5];
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
```

---

`arr` is an "array 1 of `int`".  Because it is an array, when passed to a function, `arr` is converted to the address of its first element.  This is an `int *`: Good

```
int arr[1];
scanf("%d", arr);
```

---

`&arr` is the address of an "array 1 of `int`".  Although this has the same *value* as `&arr[0]`, it is not an `int *`: Bad

```
int arr[1];
scanf("%d", &arr); // Bad
```

---

**Result** `scanf("%d", ...` needs an `int *` argument.

1. When the modifiable object being passed converts to an `int`, an `&` is needed.
2. When the object being passed converts to an `int *`, no `&` is needed.